# How to rollup records having not null values for each column in db2 Sql?

Tags: sql, db2, dynamic-sql

I have a table as below-

| id | name | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 | null | null |
| 1 | aaa | null | 1 | null |
| 1 | aaa | null | null | 1 |
| 1 | aaa | null | null | 2 |
| 1 | aaa | null | 1 | null |
| 2 | bbb | null | null | null |
| 2 | bbb | 1 | null | null |

i want the output as below-

| id | name | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | aaa | null | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | bbb | 1 | null | null |

i tried doing this:

```
select id ,name, max(col1),max(col2),max(col3) 
from table group by id, name;
```

but the output is this, which is not as expected

| id | name | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 | 1 | 2 |

can u pls help me achieve the desired output.
many thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to explain what's the logic behind your desired output. It's not clear how you want to produce those two rows based on provided sample data

Comment: Perhaps `group by id, name, greatest(col1, col2, col3)`?

Comment: HI @eshirvana thanks for your reply, i want to club all the record in first row as shown in Table 2, but then next record to be created if there in more than one not null value in any columns. the attempt i made gives me the max value and returns single row which i don't want, i want all values, number of records for a group should be = to column having maximum not null values. hope this explains.

Comment: @jarlh can you pls elaborate here, how this works.

Comment: Does it work is my question? Add more sample data, having different combinations, and see if you still think it works.

Comment: @jarlh no it doesn't work, i gave a try.

Comment: Rows in a table are not ordered "by default". Show the order rule for your table records. That is, why, for example, the last row is 4-th,  and not, say, 3-rd.

Comment: hi @MarkBarinstein thanks for your reply, to answer you, my table is in the same order as shown in table 1 no change in row order.

Comment: my problem statement is somewhat like this- there is a feature in MS Word/ Excel to left align your text if you don't want center alignment or an other, similarly i want my table to be top aligned( i want to remove all the first null values of each column ) and num of records should be = column having maximum not null values (from this column nulls to removed from top and bottom also if exists)

Comment: HI @MarkBarinstein the order may change, let say from table 1 the 1st record can participate as 2nd , 3rd may come st and so onn. still i want to club and align on top. can u help here?

Comment: Ok, arbitrary order of rows. Does your table have 4 rows only? If not, than what happens with the result desired, if, say, you have 5-th row with (col1, col2, col3) = (null, 1, null)? Or if you have more rows? In other words you must describe such a "clubbing algorithm" in more details. Your "then next record to be created if there in more than one not null value in any columns" description doesn't describe the algorithm, if you have more rows in your table.

Comment: yes @MarkBarinstein, my table will have many rows having multiple values but for same group i want to combine it, i have added the 5th and 6th row for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as is.

Firstly, the rows in each group specified by (id, name) columns are enumerated. Note, that if you don't use the order by clause in the row_number function (as in the example), such an enumeration may be done in some non-repeatable and non-predictable way. So, if you want a repeatable result, you should have a way to order the rows explicitly. I've added an additional row, and you may use it uncommenting the order by clause to get the exact result as you specified in the question.

Secondly, the rows in each group are processed with a Recursive Common Table Expression statement. A new surrogate column grp (additional group number inside each group) is introduced. The first row of each group (having rn_=1) gets all the original values and grp=1. The grp value of each next row is increased by 1, if the the value of c1, c2 or c3 in this next row is not null and a value in a previous row of the corresponding column is non null as well.
If the group number is not increased, a non-null value from a previous row is copied instead the current value for each cx.
If it is increased, the current row values are retained.

Finally, we use this surrogate group number in the group by clause.
[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=4fa7d86dce97285b2040ea5912920c59).

```
with mytab (id, name, c1, c2, c3, ord) as
(
values
  (1, 'aaa', 1, null::int, null::int, 10)
, (1, 'aaa', null, 1, null, 20)
, (1, 'aaa', null, null, 1, 30)
, (1, 'aaa', null, null, 2, 40)
, (1, 'aaa', null, 1, null, 50)
, (2, 'bbb', null, null, null, 1)
, (2, 'bbb', 1, null, null, 2)
)
-- Rows enumeration inside all groups
, mytab2 as 
(
select row_number () over (partition by id, name
--order by ord
) rn_, t.*
from mytab t
)
--
, a (id, name, rn_, grp, c1, c2, c3) as
(
select id, name, rn_, 1 as grp, c1, c2, c3 
from mytab2
where rn_ = 1
  union all
select t.id, t.name, t.rn_
, a.grp 
+ case 
    when a.c1 is not null and t.c1 is not null
      or a.c2 is not null and t.c2 is not null
      or a.c3 is not null and t.c3 is not null
    then 1
    else 0
  end as grp
, case 
    when a.c1 is not null and t.c1 is not null
      or a.c2 is not null and t.c2 is not null
      or a.c3 is not null and t.c3 is not null
    then t.c1
    else coalesce (a.c1, t.c1)
  end as c1
, case 
    when a.c1 is not null and t.c1 is not null
      or a.c2 is not null and t.c2 is not null
      or a.c3 is not null and t.c3 is not null
    then t.c2
    else coalesce (a.c2, t.c2)
  end as c2
, case 
    when a.c1 is not null and t.c1 is not null
      or a.c2 is not null and t.c2 is not null
      or a.c3 is not null and t.c3 is not null
    then t.c3
    else coalesce (a.c3, t.c3)
  end as c3
from a, mytab2 t
where t.id = a.id and t.name = a.name and t.rn_ = a.rn_ + 1
)
select id, name
, max (c1) as c1
, max (c2) as c2
, max (c3) as c3
from a
group by id, name, grp
```